# Choosing a Database to store Report Json

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, cassandra, redis

I am trying to figure out which DB to use for a project with the following requirements,

Requirements:

1. scalability should be high, availability should be high
2. Data format is Json Document of several MBs in size
3. Query capabilities are my least concern, More of a key-value usecase
4. High performance/ low latency

i considered MongoDb, Cassandra, Redis, postgres (jsonb), a few other document oriented DBs, embedded databases ( small footprint will be a plus ).

Please help me find out which DB will be the best choice.

i wont need document/row wise comparison queries at all. at most requirement will be subset pick from the document. What i am looking for is a lightweight db with smaller footprint and low latency with high scalability. very low query capabilities are acceptable. should i be choosing embedded DBs? What are the points to consider here?

thanks for the help!.

Answer (score 0):

If you use documents (json) use a document database. Especially if the documents differ in structure.

PostgreSQL does not scale horizontally. Have a look at CockroachDB if you like.

Cassandra can do key-value at scale as redis, but both are not really document databases.

I would suggest MongoDB or CouchDB - which one would be a good match depends on your needs. MongoDB is consistent and partition tolerant while CouchDB is partition tolerant and available.

If you can live with some limits for querying and like high availability try out CouchDB.

Comment: This link might also be useful: https://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Comment: @Nick could you be so kind to provide some detail? 

As far as I know, plain vanilla PostgreSQL can not scale horizontally across servers in a simple multi-master fashion - except for read-only queries from a bunch of streaming replicas. 

There are third party modules for that - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Clustering but that is not build in.